# How set up Prettier and ESLint in my Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm use VSCode for writing on ReactJS, so I use .js and .jsx files, but i have a problem with formating my code. Early my Prettier works good, but now it not working, code not formating when I try save it (CRTL+S).

This is code of my settings.json

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true, //Not working :(
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4, //But real tabWidth is 2, and I'm wanna fix it too
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "all",
    "prettier.semi": true,
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 100,
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
        "enable": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the settings.json file inside the .vscode directory?

Comment: @JesusAguas, yes, http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2021/02/07/0017/3494/1133990/90/23b0615b0f.jpg

Comment: And do you have the prettier extension installed?

Comment: @JesusAguas, of course

Comment: Then everything should be fine. Can you share your .prettierrc file as well to see if there is any error?

Comment: @JesusAguas, Where should it be?

Comment: In your root directory. You need a .prettierrc file to specify how you want your files to be formatted. See: https://www.codereadability.com/automated-code-formatting-with-prettier/